# Node server crashes when trying to save mongoose document with unique index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, unique

I have a collection which has one of it's fields as a unique field.

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     code:          {type:String, required:true},
     name:          {type:String, default:""}
});

ProductSchema.index({ code: 1}, { unique: true });
```

When I create a new document with a code that already exists, the server crashes instead of returning an error through the callback:

```
module.exports.create = function (params, callback){

    var product = new ProductModel(params);
    product.save(function(error){
         console.log(error);
         callback(error);
    });
}
```

Is this (the crash) the expected behavior or mongoose should be returning an error through the callback and not crash?

here's the error I get when saving the second document with same code:

```
[..path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:245
        throw message;      
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at [...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:114:55
    at [...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1132:7
    at [...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1846:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler ([...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:445:41)
    at [...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:478:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody ([...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> ([...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:436:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> ([...path]/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:201:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

Comment: I think you spotted a nice bug

Answer (score 1):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Put an error handler on the save for the product directly:

```
ProductModel.on('error', function(){..});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Server keeps crashing 
    `var ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
    ProductSchema.on('error', function(error){ 
        console.log(error); 
    });`